# View multiple items in the new review tool

Tags: discussion, review

The new review tool is very neat, but it appears to display items one-by-one, and won't show me a new item until I've definitively made up my mind about the currently displayed one.

Is there a way of viewing a larger number of pending items all at once and picking one, similar to how it used to be with the pending edit requests?

My problem is that many of the items are in subjects which are completely alien to me, and so I don't have *any* useful or calibrated judgment about what makes an acceptable answer or what's a useful edit. In the past I just used to scan the entire set of pending requests for things I'd recognize and submit my contribution to those.

At the moment, if I feel like reviewing some items and open the tool, I'm presented with one, two, three posts that I know nothing about and give up because I don't feel that I'm able to contribute anything useful. If I could view multiple items at once (say 50?), I could spot the 10 that I understand and deal with them.

Comment: I've been complaining about this since the beta began. :P

Comment: Why not just click the "Not sure" button? That's what I am doing and it works just fine.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Because it's uninteresting and demotivating to sit and click in front of nine posts I have absolutely no understanding about. With a multiview, I could scan and pick out something that jumps out at me, eagle-eye style, without ever needing to engage mentally with things that *don't* suggest themselves to me.

Comment: Well, I do prefer the new way and the dry numbers appear to agree - since the change was deployed on Stack Overflow it's rare to see the edit queue with more than 10 items while before that it was almost full most of the time.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: OK, that's nice. I was merely hoping for an *option* or so to display more than one item, but of course the default should stay as it is, especially if it gets more work done.

Comment: Cheers, maybe the efficiency is result of adding the [stats page](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/stats) so now it's much more.. competitive. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are allowed a huge amount of "not sure" votes during review.  We do prioritize the review queue by tags that you have marked interesting.  We are working on ways to send you review tasks that will better match your skill and engagement.

Comment: I understand that I could say "not sure", but there's a *much* larger amount of mental engagement involved in processing a single post and making a decision to say "not sure" than there is in scanning over a large list of posts and letting the occasional *interesting* item pop out at me. Maybe it's best compared to the difference between polling and interrupt?

Comment: "huge amount"? Do you mean there *is* a limit?

Comment: There is no limit at the moment @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: Question: Do tag edits by juniors trigger an edit review request? I believe I just witnessed someone editing (physically informing me of the fact) but no request showing up in my review queue.